# Mario.c coding issue

Tags: c

I'm having some trouble with my code and I'm not sure as to what the error message is trying to tell me is wrong with what I have. (Please see image)

Any suggestions?

Btw, it says error: expected identifier '(' in the terminal window as well.

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as formatted text instead of a screenshot. And the exact error with line number.

Comment: As an aside, should you have `spaces != 0` in the second `for` statement? Or even (as a precaution from the calculation) `spaces > 0` ?

Comment: `int all_rows;int space;` --> `int rows;int spaces;` as typo

Comment: And `int hash` --> `int hashes` too. Anything wrong with `height`?

Comment: Sorry for the screenshot, had to be quick. The suggestions worked out, but my pyramid is upside down so just trying to work that out now.

Answer (score 4):

Here is your problem

```
int main(void);
```

Please remove the final `;` since you are declaring a function prototype, not a function implementation. So, the following statements are out of context, because they are not within the body of any function.